# Text shows the wrong way - Unity bug?

Tags: unity, bug

I was working in the next scene, the font I used has worked well in another scene, but why when I go back to this "main menu" scene does the font look destroyed (previously show well)?

Screenshot :
[image: easter egg]

I tried everything from resizing, reinputting text, and redownloading the font asset but it keep show like this. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a known bug in Unity for a while now.  The Text will get garbled up like that randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reinstalling unity fix the problem !

[image: EASTER EGG]

Comment: You should mark this as an answer.